# DNS zone file issue after upgrading from Ubuntu LTS 12.4.4 to Ubuntu LTS14.04

Tags: dns

I have 3 dns servers. The 2nd and 3rd dns servers are slave from the 1st or primary server. All my server are running Ubuntu Server LTS12.4.4 and I would like to upgrade them to the lastest version, which is Ubuntu Server LTS 14.04.

Therefore, I follow the upgrade procedure on the 3rd DNS server and the upgrade was successful. Then, I need to test and make sure the slave or the transfer of the dns zone file from the primary server are working. To do that, I delete one of the domain name zone file on the 3rd dns server and then run "sudo service bind9 restart". It suppose to re-create that domain name zone file and it did and I checked the log and there is no error and everything is successful.

However, when I run the "cat domain-name-zone-file" or "more domain-name-zone-file" or "vi domain-name-zone-file" or "nano domain-name-zone-file", it display binary data or the format in the domain-name-zone-file are not readable when I run the "cat, more, vi or nano" commands.

Anyone know what my issues maybe. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error, this behavior is supported by bind 9
Look at the first answer here - https://serverfault.com/questions/488092/binary-zone-file-on-bind9